# Failed to save: insufficient permissions in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to save a file, but every time I try to the following error (as shown in the image) comes up. I run the code from the terminal using sudo and it still is not working and I tried changing owners of the file in the terminal, although I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Retry as sudo just pulls up the same error.

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i9vP.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can change the ownership of you project file. That might work.

```
sudo chown -c -R $USER:$USER (project folder)
```

Explanation:

- chown: change the ownership of files/directories
- -c: report all changes
- -R: do this recursively (for all files/directories beneath the given one)
- $USER:$USER: change the owner and the group that owns the the entry
  to the user that issues the command (sudo preserves the values)
- (project folder): name of the folder which contains project files

You can test those environment variables with the following commands

```
echo $USER
sudo echo $USER
```

Comment: this is not the problem for me. i am working in a directory with many files in, it's something typescript related it seems